# How to add a mini log-in form in the left bar of home?

Tags: login, column, sidebar

English is not my native language so apologies in advance for bad grammar.

I am building a Magento page, but I need a mini-login form showing at the left-bar if the user is not logged in. If it is, show the user's shopping cart.

Searching for an answer I ended up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931195/magento-add-login-myaccount-widget-in-sidebar, but the answer does not give a proper way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! We need more information to provide you with a concrete approach. Can you show your work? Can you give us some code to review? Any more information you can provide us will help us to point you to a solution. At present we just don't have enough information to provide a solid approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this 
you need to add below code at your `layout xml file` like `customer.xml or local.xml` which located at `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTemplate/layout/`

```
<customer_logged_out>
<reference name="left">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_mini_login" before="-" template="customer/form/mini.login.phtml"/>
        </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Here  using reference tag  left  (`<reference name="left">`) the customer mini login will be shown on `left panel of your magento instance` whenever page  layout is `2-columns-left.phtml or 3-columns.phtml`

If want to show only on home then need put a condition like 
**current controller full action**`(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()`) is cms_index_index

```
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()=='cms_index_index' ):
........
endif;
```

**Note:** You need to add form_key as input field in form

`<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />` for magento 1.9 all version.

Comment: I am still lost. i don't know where to put the reference tag left (<reference name="left">). on witch document or it is on the CMS menu of admin?

Comment: i am a dork, i just need to refresh the cache. thx a lot!!